# How do you use REST/HTTP with a body as a source in an ADF copy activity?

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I cannot seem to be be able to use a REST-source with the the body as dynamic content from a previous lookup-activity. The body content in the REST API call will be messed up with "" and "\n" characters. I noticed data factory automatically adds braces to dynamic content:

[image]

Removing the braces from the code view results in an error when running the pipeline. I have tested the same API call with a web activity, in which the body will be formatted correctly:

[image]

However, I don't know how you can save the response as a file from a web activity. In recap, I want to dynamically pass the Body to a REST API and save the response as a json file. How should this be achieved?

Comment: I think there is a different between Web Activity and Copy Data activity with REST a source
I tried both json and string functions in Copy Data Activity Request Body , but it gives me 406 error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't used this scenario myself, but two things come to mind:

**1)** Assuming the body needs to be JSON, so you may need to convert the lookup value [which I assume is a string] using the [json](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/control-flow-expression-language-functions#json) expression. Something like

```
@{json(activity('Lookup1').output.value)}
```

**2)** Under additional headers, you may need to add an entry to specify Content-Type: application/json

Comment: I tried using the json function as you suggested, but cannot get it to work even with a static call like this: @{json('{"Type": "ID","Value": "ABC123"}')}. 
The call will look like this (with added "\"-symbols):

        "requestBody": "{\"Type\":\"ID\",\"Value\":\"ABC123\"}",

Which will result in a faulty call. I suppose ADF does some kind of special character escaping, Is this something you need to avoid somehow?

Comment: Definitely looks like character escaping, but I'm not sure what is causing it.

Comment: I'm not sure what I did wrong earlier, but managed to get it to work in the original way. Your answer should then work if the lookup value is a String (in my case I needed to pass the lookup as-is)